Large channel count (100+) measurement solution?
I am a mechanical engineer by trade, so please correct my assumptions if they are wrong. I'm designing a test rig for my company's electrolyzer design. The electrolyzer will have anywhere from 128-200 individual cells, which I need to obtain a cell voltage measurement for each of. The entire stack is wired in series, with a stack voltage of 300V (128 cells) and
up to 106A current. Each cell will have a voltage of ~2.5V. What is the simplest and least-headache solution to get this number of voltage measurements? I'd want each channel to be safe up to 3V, just in case. For communications protocols, Modbus TCP or ethernet IP both integrate well with our controls software (Ignition SCADA).

Are you asking for advice on electronics design / topology, or for recommendation of an off-the-shelf BMS type solution? (the latter is off-topic here, sorry... please feel free to clarify by editing your question)

Some COTS BMS ICs are stackable, perhaps all the way up to 300 V. That could be an option for you. Do you need to measure all the way down to 0 V?

What kind of SNR/Noise specs do you need?

Well, if you want to set a limit, you'll need to take feedback from somewhere that controls your entire current stack. What is your limit and intention? Maybe someone could suggest a peripheral with a SCADA-compatible interface, but you should be more specific about it. Measuring cell voltage would be easy in the system you're trying to build.

Is there a risk of a cell failing open-circuit?  such an event could be disasterous to many designs.

No responses to question from OP. VTC.

With speed/accuracy information missing, let's throw up a strawman and see how many of the OP's assumptions it hits.
With 100 A flowing through the cells, there may be the opportunity to steal a few mA from the cells to power the monitors.
I am a great fan of building something relatively small and simple, then replicating it until it meets the scale of the requirement. That's great for flexibility, and also for swapping out good/bad ones for fault finding.
Design a measurement module that connects directly across perhaps 8 series cells, which puts the min/max voltage across the stack in the nice, safe, obtainable components sort of range. Have a straightforward ADC/MCU design to measure the inputs, then use an opto-isolated serial output from each module to a controller. All modules read separately if high speed is needed, but the outputs could be wire-ORed to one channel for economy at low speed. Handle the final protocol at the controller.
The use of lots of small cheap modules may affect how you value input protection, in the event of a single cell going open circuit. If you had one large system, then you might want to protect all your inputs very robustly to 300 V. It may well be cheaper to accept one small module failing in the open circuit event, than to have to over-engineer all of the input protection.


I'd want each channel to be safe up to 3V, just in case.

If the total stack voltage is 300V and one cell opens for any reason, for example a broken wire, bad contact, etc... then the full stack voltage will appear across this cell. So each channel should be safe up to the full stack voltage.
Having one circuit per cell or for small groups of cells, and powering these circuits from cell voltage themselves seems practical, but introduces two problems:

If one cell is shorted, or has an unexpected low voltage, then the circuit powered from it will be unpowered.

In this case the circuit won't send measured voltages: there is no way to know if this is a problem with the circuit breaking down or being unpowered due to a cell having too low voltage. Likewise during start-up it is not possible to measure anything until cell voltages are established and allow the circuits to be powered. So it's not possible to start up the electrolyzer at low power, check if everything works, then ramp up the power.

Need for a power supply that will work fine with 2.5V nominal, but maybe less, and not burn when it occasionally receives 300V.

This is a bit outside of the range of the usual boost converter chip or LDO. It's doable, for example with a depletion MOSFET wired as a current limiter, but it looks like a potential headache... especially if you have a hundred of these, they have to be cheap and not dissipate a lot of power because everything is multiplied by 100: cost, heat, complexity, etc.
On top of this, with currents like 100A you have to consider that if a wire gets loose, due to the inductance in the circuit, there will be a large inductive kickback with an arc and probably a huge voltage spike. So the 300V upper voltage range seems optimistic. If we want it to be reliable it should be increased to "much higher than 300V, but not for very long."
This blows up the headache implied by powering it from the cells. It also points to a voltage measurement circuit with a high input impedance, thus low input current, which means it can be made safe up to very high input voltages simply by adding series resistors and protection diodes to the inputs.
Suggestions:
#1 I was originally going to suggest using a BMS chip with SPI interface isolated with optos. These chips measure voltage on a series string of lithium cells, so they'd do exactly what you want. Here's an example. However, the internal measurement amplifiers are powered from the cell voltages so they require a rather low resistance (<1k) connection to the cells, which conflicts with the high voltage protection requiremnt.
#2 A module with say 8 inputs, so with 2.5-3V across each cell this gives a normal input range of max 24V which fits inside the input range of a +/-15V supply instrumentation amplifier. Then for each input, protection with resistors and diodes, one instrumentation amplifier, then a microcontroller ADC input. But +/-15V INAs are a bit expensive and you need a lot of them.
#3 A simplification would be to replace the instrumentation amps with difference amps (substractors). You'll need 0.1% resistors and lose precision, but it'll be a lot cheaper. A useful feature of the difference amp is that it can measure voltages outside of its supply voltage range, although how far outside depends on the gain.
Also a difference amp has resistors in series with the inputs already, which simplifies input protection.
#4 8 channels per board, with two 8:1 analog muxes in front of a single instrumentation or difference amplifier. In this case the input protection resistors need to be placed before the mux.
#5 A cheap opamp and a MOSFET make a neat "instrumentation amplifier" with a few restrictions: input voltage must be inside the opamp's input common mode, and higher than output voltage plus a small margin for the MOSFET. Besides that, the circuit already incorporates input protection resistors ; if their value is high enough you can even use the opamp's input protection diodes and skip external ones. A FET input opamp would be best.

